# Polymorphic iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, range, polymorphism

I'm working with a C++ template structure Node and a complex collection class Collection that stores pointers to these Node objects. The Node structure is defined as follows:

```
template <typename T>
struct Node {
    T data;
    // Other methods and members
};
```

The collection class is templated and holds `Node` pointers:

```
template <typename T> 
class Collection {
     Node* root;
      
     std::vector<Node*> query(Condition condition); 
     ...
};
```

I also have a function `FoosConsumer` that processes a range of `Foo` objects:

```
template <typename FooRange>
void FoosConsumer(FooRange &foos) {
    for(Foo &foo : foos) {
        // Do something with foo
    }
}
```

The issue arises when I need to query my collection to fetch either the nodes themselves or just the data member of these nodes. Ideally, I want to directly iterate over data elements of the nodes returned by `collection.query(condition)`, and then pass them to `FoosConsumer`. Here's what I'd like to achieve:

```
int main() {
    DataCollection<Foo> collection;

    // Can iterate over nodes
    for(auto &node : collection.query(condition)) { ... }

    // If I need to access `data` I do this:
    for(auto &node : collection.query(condition)) { 
        Foo &data = node.data;
    }

    // My desire: Iterate over `data` of each node directly
    for(Foo &el : collection.query(condition)) { ... }

    // The intended use case is:
    FoosConsumer(collection.query(condition));
}
```

Currently, I'm using a workaround that feels inefficient and cumbersome:

```
std::vector<Foo*> tmp;
for(Node<Foo> &node : collection.query(condition)) {
    tmp.push_back(&node.data);
}
FoosConsumer(tmp);
```

Is there a more elegant way to directly iterate over the data members of the nodes in my collection? I'm looking for a solution that allows seamless iteration over the data attribute without the need for an intermediate container or additional loops.

I could indeed implement a custom iterator or a proxy:

```
for(Node &node : collection.queryNode(condition)) {}
for(Data &node : collection.queryFoo(condition)) {}
```

But as both `Node*` and `Data*` share the same addresses with arithmetic on `Node` size I am sure there is a trick.

Comment: Do you have C++20 (or can you use the [Range-v3](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/) library)?

Comment: Indeed, I do use C++20

Comment: There is no such thing as `Node*` because it's a template class.  You have to specify the template parameter as part of the type.

Comment: You need think about your data structure as a graph. Then decide about the ownership of the nodes. If ownership relation graph is a tree, some equivalent of `std::unique_ptr` can partially manage the lifetime; If the ownership forms a DAG, then `std::shared_ptr` is a good choice. Otherwise you need some god object to create, own and kill the `Node`s. Make a feasible abstraction first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I last implemented a complex `tree` structure, I ended up doing something akin to this:

```
namespace impl {
    enum node_dir {left=0,right=1};
    struct node {
        node* parent;
        node* child[2];

        const node* deep_child_to(node_dir dir) const;
        const node* next_child_to(node_dir dir) const;
        const node* parent_with_other_child_to(node_dir dir) const;
        const node* next_iter_in(node_dir dir) const;
        //etc. Most tree graph methods here, including mutating
    };
}
```

And that prevented each template type from generating the same tree-maintainance code.  The container class itself ended up being trivial, though required an awkward cast:

```
template<class T>
class container {
    struct node : impl::node {
         std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)> buffer;
         //details...
    };
    T& data(impl::node* n) {return static_cast<node>(n).buffer;}
    impl::node root = {};

public:
    T& first() {return data(root->deep_child_to(impl::left));}
    void push_back(T& v) {root->push_back(new node(v));}
    //etc.  Almost every method was exactly one line.
    //note the class NEVER exposes `node` or `impl::node` publicly.
}
```

The fact that the template class' methods are each exactly one line helps affirm that minimal code is duplicated between instances.

The iterators work on basically the same principle. They're have a `node*` and call `next_iter_in(dir)`, and then cast it to `container<node>` to extract the `data`.  With these principles, your `query` methods can likewise operate on `impl::node`, and only cast to `T` at the user boundaries.

Also note that the use of `node_dir` and `child[2]` allows me to use the same C++ and binary code to mirror every operation.